# How to set brightness and color temperature in iMac late 2009 after setting nomodeset?

Tags: display, brightness, amd-graphics, radeon, mac

I am running Kubuntu 22.04 on an [iMac late 2009 27 inch](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP696?locale=en_US). It is also known as [iMac 11,1](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i7-2.8-27-inch-aluminum-late-2009-specs.html).

This computer has `AMD ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4850` graphics, and it only shows a black screen beyond grub unless the `nomodeset` option is set.

Now, there is no way to change brightness or color temperature.

The `xrandr` output is

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 2560 x 1440, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 2560 x 1440
default connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   2560x1440     93.00*
```

`xrandr` cannot change screen contrast because it cannot set gamma size. As a result, tools like redshift (or KDE Night Color) do not work.

The output of `ls /sys/class/backlight/` is blank. I tried setting `acpi_backlight=vendor` and `acpi_backlight=native` in `/etc/default/grub`, but it does nothing.

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -c video`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV770/M98L [Mobility Radeon HD 4850]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0620000-d062ffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0600000-d061ffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=2560,1440
```

How to set brightness and color temperature? Even if `xrandr` does not work, there is some software that is showing the colors in screen. Is there any way to change its contrast or color temperature?

Comment: The requirement of `nomodeset` indicates a major problem with how the graphics are set up. Check your drivers; ensure that `libdrm-radeon1` and `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` are installed. `amdgpu` does not work with your graphics card.

Comment: Yes, both `libdrm-radeon1` and `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` are installed. I found on the internet that it does not work without nomodeset (and that turned out to be true)

Comment: After walking through some forums, the conclusion is that bugs in the `radeon` driver are making similar hardware malfunction. While I would say "wait patiently for a fix", considering the issue remains unfixed for a loooong time... :shrug:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partial answer for screen brightness**: I found a workaround for screen brightness.

Reinstall OSX (if not already installed).
Install Ubuntu as a dual boot with OSX.
Set up rEFInd for dual boot, and ensure `nomodeset` is enabled in Ubuntu.

Afterwards, set brightness within OSX. It will be retained across the dual boot, when you run Ubuntu.