# Is nomodeset still necessary after configuring rEFInd in an iMac?

Tags: 22.04, mac, nomodeset, refind

I have an iMac 2009, which does not show anything past the grub screen without nomodeset, and has [graphics issues](https://askubuntu.com/q/1503557/124466) despite using nomodeset.

There are some old answers concerning iMacs, which suggest installing `rEFInd` in old iMacs.

Is `nomodeset` still necessary if I configure `rEFInd`?

I am using Kubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Aren't they two different things? rEFInd is a boot manager. nomodeset is a kernel option.

Comment: I see. rEFInd is probably only necessary if one wants to dual boot macOS and Ubuntu, right? And it has nothing to do with nomodeset?